What supporting documentation do I need for splitting federal withholdings in a community property state?
I live in a community property state and got a letter from the IRS on my partner's 2022 federal return (similar to Where on 1040 do I indicate withholding adjustments in a community property state (form 8958)?). The difference in stated amount of tax owed is exactly equal to the community property adjustment we had, which makes me think that I filled out the 8958 form incorrectly. Under wages (and the other sections), I had written out the total amount for each of our incomes in column A with how much each of us received in columns B and C. Was I supposed to split column A evenly into B and C if I wanted to indicate that we were sharing income and tax withholdings?
Also, how should I respond to the letter? Should I re-fill out the 8958 and write a letter explaining the mistake?


Was I supposed to split column A evenly into B and C if I wanted to indicate that we were sharing income and tax withholdings?

You were supposed to report the facts. As a general rule, community income is shared equally. This is governed by the State law. In different States the definitions of what's community and what's separate may differ slightly. For community income, it doesn't matter which one of you earned it. Withholding, if from community income, are also shared. Separate income, and withholding from it, are allocated to the partner to whom it belongs.

Also, how should I respond to the letter? Should I re-fill out the 8958 and write a letter explaining the mistake?

I strongly advise talking to a tax professional first. You might both need to file amended returns.
